# How can I change my form method from GET to POST?

Tags: php, forms, post, methods, crud

```
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; 

if (isset($_POST["del"])) {
    echo "Hi";
} else {
    echo "Bye";
}
```

I'm making a simple crud Blog app with php, I have done Select and Create now I was doing delete using a bootstrap modal and for that I've to send ID, so I used hidden input method and made it a form, but now my form method is get all the time, I had done everything but couldn't find a way to make it post...

Comment: `<form method="POST">`

Comment: <form action='". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ."' method='POST'> I had already done this...

Comment: Then it should send it as POST. Are you using AJAX instead of normal form submission?

Comment: @Barmar I'm using simple php, it is sending as get.

Comment: After reloading that page, it shows Bye, but when I click it doesn't show anything...

Comment: How are you doing a Boostrap modal without JavaScript?

Comment: Please post a [mre] with the HTML and JavaScript, showing how you're submitting the form.